# Issue due to porting in different gcc versions

Tags: c, linux, pointers, gcc

I have a C code in which I get an error in the third line:

```
struct in6_pktinfo *ptr;
ptr = (struct in6_pktinfo *) CMSG_DATA (cmsgptr);
*ifindex = ptr->ipi6_ifindex;


ERROR: dereferrencing pointer to incomplete type
```

in case of `gcc 4.6/4.7` with centos/ubuntu distro, but not in case of `gcc 2.96`

Now, how can I ascertain that this issue is due to gcc?

Comment: You *did* include `<linux/ipv6.h>`, right?

Comment: "gcc 2.96" isn't even actually a version of gcc.

Answer (score 2):

gcc 2.96 is really old you shouldn't rely on what it says.

Things like that can happen if the definition of that `struct` is inside an include file that gets included in different order because of `#ifdef` that depend on the compiler version. So you probably should check in which order things are included. Doxygen might be a valuable tool do visualize the include structure of your project.

Comment: Not only is 2.96 really old, it was never an official release.  See: http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-2.96.html.